# Getting XtraGrid filter items

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using devexpress XtraGrid. If I filtered this grid using a value related to specific column, I want to get that column(s) and value(s) in c#. Can any body help???

Regards

Comment: How are you filtering your grid? Post some code and describe in more detail your question/need.

Comment: I am filtering during run time. You just go to desired column, click on it, items appear, you select and item, and the whole grid is filtered by this item. e.g you select 'Motor' value in 'Vehicle' column and the result is all records which vehicle type = 'Motor'

Comment: so what is your question??

Comment: I want to get the filter string during run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need `GridView.ActiveFilter.Criteria` property.

It returns [CriteriaOperator](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataFilteringCriteriaOperatortopic) which is actually expression tree (just because DevExpress gridview filtering can be complex - not by single column).

In your simple case (filtering by one value in one column) you can just convert it to string by `.ToString()` and then parse string you'll get.

It will be something like `[columnName] = columnValue` string, and parsing it not a problem.

In complex cases (when it's a real expression tree) you can create your own class having implemented `IClientCriteriaVisitor` interface and traverse expression tree using `CriteriaOperator.Accept` method.

See example of such traverse implementation [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3396).

Comment: yes my situation is simple, i just want to retrieve the filter string. GridView.ActiveFilterString also gets the result. Thanks alot :)